# Do the Japanese ideographic and fullwidth full stop both map to ASCII full stop?

Tags: javascript, unicode, cjk, normalize

I noticed that NFKC unicode normalization, at least in JavaScript, does *not* normalize the Japanese ideographic full stop (。) to ASCII full stop but it does normalize the Japanese fullwidth full stop (．) to the ASCII full stop.

```
'。'.normalize('NFKC')
> '。'
'．'.normalize('NFKC')
> '.'
```

Does only the latter map to the ASCII full stop?

In Mac OS X you have the option of choosing between either of them for punctuation purposes so it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Calling "。" a "half stop" is… confusing. It's the *ideographic full stop*. The other one is the *fullwidth full stop*.

Comment: @deceze excellent point, fixed - thanks.

Comment: Western punctuation and Japanese one are not fully compatible. The reason Max OS/Windows having default punctuation selectable is that historically there are some group who preferred using West-originated punctuation letters even in Japanese text (for example, academic/engineering fields). For the rest majority, replacing "。" with "." in Japanese texts is never thought as a "normalization".

Comment: @akky why not? They are both a full stop. They _are_ fully compatible as far as intent as far as my research took me (the fact that they are both called full stop alone should be sufficient for intent.)

Comment: @AdamThompson "。" is not used as a decimal point in Japanese number, so they are not automatically exchangeable. For example, if there is a string in text like " 123。45 " in Japanese, it can never mean "123.45" but one sentence end with "123" and the other starts with "45". In precise definition, Japanese full stop letter is a pure full stop, but the English full stop letter is a full stop or a decimal point, which depends on context.

Comment: Interesting, does the Japanese language not need the concept of a decimal point?

Comment: @AdamThompson Now Japaneses use Arabic digits and (.) in Japanese text. Pan-Chinese cultures also have number names to small direction. Such like million, billion, etc. to small scale, there are names for pow(10, -1), pow(10, -2), ... https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/fractions.html So they were able to be described even before the Arabic system imported. There were no zero and decimal point concept, same as ancient Roman numeric system (MMXIX = 2019) did not have them.